# How to verify a shared secret using only AES?

Tags: aes, cbc-mac

I have two devices that need to verify that they both are in possesion of the same secret key. One of the devices is a very limited embedded device that only has AES128 available, no SHA or other hash variants.

My idea is a basic two-way challenge-response scheme:

- Device 1 generates 8 bytes of random data (C1), and sends it to Device 2
- Device 2 generates 8 bytes of random data (C2), and calculates R1 == AES(key, C1 || C2)
- Device 2 sends R1 and C2 to Device 1
- Device 1 calculates AES(key, C1 || C2) and verifies that this matches R1
- Device 1 calculates R2 == AES(key, R1)
- Device 1 sends R2 to Device 2
- Device 2 calculates AES(key, R1) and verifies that this matches R2

Or put another way:

```
D1->D2: C1
D2->D1: C2, AES(key, C1 || C2)
D1->D2: AES(key, AES(key, C1 || C2))
```

My thinking is that this is a form of CBC-MAC, where each device offers a random challenge to the other that prevents replay attacks. Since it's just one block of data being processed, the CBC-MAC weaknesses aren't a problem.

Is this a sensible way of verifying the shared secret, or should I be doing something different?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why over-complicate it like that,

- D1 and D2 generates random 64-bit P (half the block size of AES)
- they send it to each other
- both generate `AES(key,P_own||P_other)` and again send to each other (note that these are different for each)
- then both can verify that what they received is equal to `AES(key,P_other||P_own)`

Upside here is that it is a fully symmetric protocol.

Comment: Communication takes place over a 9600 baud half duplex serial line, and speed is an important aspect. But on second thought your suggestion takes as many round trips as mine… Hm.

Comment: Be careful if you choose an unauthenticated mode to encrypt `P_own||P_other` - for example if you use CTR (or CFB with a 1 block size message) an attacker can subvert the protocol by computing `E(k, P_b||P_a)` from `P_a`, `P_b` and `E(k,P_a||P_b)`; if using ECB and `P_a` and `P_b` are each a multiple of the block size, a trivial rearranging of the messages is all that is needed.

Comment: @Michael AES has a block size of 128 bits P_own and P_other both are 8 byte (64 bits) so no worries there

Comment: Indeed; suggested update to answer to make that constraint clear.